# Can't change the title and xlab of an R plot

Tags: r

I can't change the xlab of an R plot. Seems like R is giving a standard xlab and i can't change it. The new xlab overlaps the existing one. It also happens with the title.

My R code is the following:

```
data <- read.table("experiment.txt", head=TRUE, sep=",", dec=".")

tky <- TukeyHSD(aov.data, "data$window");
tky
png("window.png",width=7,height=7,units="in", res=600)
plot(tky, bty='n', cex.axis=1.2);
par(cex.main=500, lwd=2)
title(ylab="Window", cex.lab=1.2);
title(xlab="TESTE", cex.lab=1.2);
legend("topright", inset=.05, title="Window",c("1- 3x3 window","2- 5x5 window","3- 7x7  window", '4- 9x9 window', '5- All windows'), cex=1.2);
dev.off()
```

That's the output image. You can see that my xlab overlaps the standard xlab R gives

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [anselmoferreira at www.ic.unicamp.br](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Eanselmoferreira/images/janela-geral.png))</sub>

What's the problem with my code?

Comment: use `?mtext` instead of title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot function will usually allow you to suppress the default value for xlab and ylab which are taken from the names of the arguments. Just use xlab="" and ylab="". However, you are plotting with special plot function determined by the class of the object created by `TukeyHSD` and that is not going to succeed.

```
> plot(TukeyHSD(fm1, "tension"), ylab="")
Error in plot.default(c(xi[, "lwr"], xi[, "upr"]), rep.int(yvals, 2L),  : 
  formal argument "ylab" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

So you either need to hack at `plot.TukeyHSD` or move your annotation up or down to avoid colliding with the default label. That's what @EDi is telling you when suggesting using `mtext`. You can also move the labels away from the plot regions with the "line" parameter. Try this:

```
 title(xlab="TESTE", line=4)
```

Comment: OK. But how to get rid of the standard xlabel R gives?

Comment: I told you, two choices: if needing to modify the default ... then hack `plot.TukeyHSD`. It's a fairly small bit of code and will be very easy to shape to your purposes.